# Component doesn't display Data from my API

Tags: api, angular, components, angular2-services, angular2-http

I am trying to load and display a list of users from my API, but my list does not display when the page has finished loading.

I have to make another interaction (click on a button for example) to display the list. [view of my example](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=129231api.gif)

But when i'm loading users from "mocks" i have no problems

my component :

```js
import { Component,ViewEncapsulation, OnInit}  from '@angular/core';
import { UserService }                          from './services/user.service';
import { User }            from './class/user'
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject}       from "rxjs";

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <li *ngFor="let user of users" >{{user.username}}</li>
 <span (click) = 'log'>log</span>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
 users : User[] 

 constructor( private userService: UserService){ }

 ngOnInit(){
  this.userService
      .getUsers()
      .then((res) => { 
                       if (res.users){
                                        this.users = res.users;} 
        });
 }

 log(){
  console.log(this.users)
 }
```

my service :

```html
import { Injectable }                 from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, Response }    from '@angular/http'; 
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { LocalStorage }               from '../class/local-storage';
import { User }                       from '../class/user';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

    private apiUrl = 'https://localhost:4000/';
    users : User[];
    private token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  
  constructor(private http : Http) {}

  getUsers(){
        return this.http
                   .get(this.apiUrl + 'users?token=' + this.token)
                   .toPromise()
                   .then(res => res.json())
  }
}
```

Comment: whats the error ?

Comment: no error,  my list does not appear, i have to do something on my page (clicking on a button for example) and my list appear. [link](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=129231api.gif)

Comment: what kind response  returns your API ? can you able to show a response

Comment: my api returns a json object like this : `{
  "page": 1,
  "users": [
    {
      "id": 32,
      "username": "admin",
      "password": "admin",
      "salt": "wL2OB6ylkNK7rrd81OFwPg+FnJi09yKgBg7b1EtitnUJfHF+dZmltxl/NKRgtCTq+",
      "createdAt": "2016-08-25T13:14:03.000Z",
      "updatedAt": "2016-08-25T13:14:03.000Z"
    }
  ]
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
<span (click)='log'>log</span>
```

should be

```
<span (click)='log()'>log</span>
```

also try using `elvis operator` i.e `?` like this

```
<li *ngFor="let user of users" >{{user?.username}}</li>
```

this mean whenever the data is availabel it will reflact changes and dont allow angular to show error,

still if you have any problem provide plunker with your plunker and comment here is need any problem.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but there are no difference, when i'm loading users from "mocks" i have no problems. I think my problem comes from the call of my service